# Is there any way to send a value through signal

Tags: linux, signals, ipc

I am programming a program with 2 process, parent process forks to generate a child process.  And my problem is that i wanna send a value from parent to child in a most simple way. Can i do it with signal or any other IPC(most simple). Thank All !!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Data can be sent/received with a signal -
at least on systems supporting `sigqueue()` and `sigaction()` with `SA_SIGINFO`.
Example for the receiving process:

```
#include <signal.h>
#include <string.h>

void usr1(int sig, siginfo_t *sip, void *ptr)
{
    printf("sival_int %d\n", sip->si_value.sival_int);
}

. . .

    struct sigaction sa;

    memset(&sa, 0, sizeof (sa));
    sa.sa_sigaction = usr1;
    sa.sa_flags = SA_SIGINFO;
    sigaction(SIGUSR1, &sa, NULL);
```

Example for the sending process:

```
#include <signal.h>

. . .

    union sigval sv;

    sv.sival_int = 43210;
    sigqueue(target_pid, SIGUSR1, sv);
```

See `union sigval` for another choice.
Manual pages: [sigaction](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/sigaction.2.html), [sigqueue](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/sigqueue.3.html)

Comment: really useful answer to me, Thanks !

Comment: It would be interesting to know if the `sigval_ptr` of the `sigval` union could be used to pass more than one integer to the handling process (I guess virtual adress space keeps the data the pointer is referencing separated but I am not sure)...